# When I have a RDS managed database, do I still need a backend server or can I pool from the frontend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

PERN stack for reference

Before this, I would put Postgres, Express on a server and have my backend, the other server would connect to it. (backend) <-> (frontend)

Now that I signed up for a managed database(AWS RDS), I am not sure how to implement the same thing. I can only connect to RDS with postgres so do I need a backend to connect to RDS so basically 2 backends kinda like this (RDS) <-> (backend) <-> (frontend) or can I just pool into the RDS from my front end without any routes or express code?

Comment: How would you ensure security of RDS connection details (username, password, host) if you connect from frontend only? Generally, you still need backend to connect to RDS for security reasons at the least.

Comment: You don't really want to expose your database directly to the public. You can Google and do some research as to why not. So ideally you have a backend or web service API that acts as an intermediate between your front end and your database

Comment: I was just confused at first that I need to get twice the computing power in comparison to a self-hosted Postgres server where you can have both the express and DB.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly one way to build a solution here is to have a front end (your view) display the data queried from the RDS database. However, the logic to connect to it is invoked from a controller. That is, when a request is made to query data, the controller invokes a Service that has logic to open a connection to the RDS instance and query data from it and then return a result set that is displayed in the view. This way, the view knows nothing about how to connect to the database and only how to display the result set.